# Allocatable GPU is none in EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ec2, gpu, amazon-eks, gpuimage

I got none allocatable GPU after I provisioned an EKS cluster with GPU instance.

kubectl get nodes "-o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name ,GPU:.status.allocatable.nvidia.com/gpu"

```
NAME                                       GPU
ip-10-2-2-71.us-west-2.compute.internal    <none>
ip-10-2-3-146.us-west-2.compute.internal   <none>
ip-10-2-4-217.us-west-2.compute.internal   <none>
```

As follows are steps I built the customized ubuntu image:

1. Install docker:
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
2. Install NVIDIA-docker
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-nvidia-driver.html#nvidia-installation-options

I chose Option 3 for G5 instance (I launched an EC2 instance with G5.4xlarge and built the AMI)
Option 3: GRID drivers (G5, G4dn, and G3 instances)
G5 instances require GRID 13.1 or later (or GRID 12.4 or later).

Installed CUDA 11.6
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://ec2-linux-nvidia-drivers/latest/ .

Installed the docker utilit engine for NVIDIA GPUS.

https://docs.nvidia.com/ai-enterprise/deployment-guide/dg-docker.html

ENABLING THE DOCKER REPOSITORY AND INSTALLING THE NVIDIA CONTAINER TOOLKIT

sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 510.85.02    Driver Version: 510.85.02    CUDA Version: 11.6     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A10G         On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   16C    P8    15W / 300W |      0MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

3. I provisioned EKS cluster, using Karpenter launched GPU nodes. I installed k8s-device-plugin

https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin

I configure docker as follows in the AMI:

```
{
    "default-runtime": "nvidia",
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
```

Enabling GPU Support in Kubernetes

$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/v0.12.3/nvidia-device-plugin.yml

```
 kubectl get daemonset -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
kube-system   aws-node                              3         3         3       3            3           <none>          25h
kube-system   kube-proxy                            3         3         3       3            3           <none>          25h
kube-system   nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset        3         3         3       3            3           <none>          86m
```

kubectl get nodes "-o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name ,GPU:.status.allocatable.nvidia.com/gpu"

```
NAME                                       GPU
ip-10-2-2-71.us-west-2.compute.internal    <none>
ip-10-2-3-146.us-west-2.compute.internal   <none>
ip-10-2-4-217.us-west-2.compute.internal   <none>
```

Comment: I found out that it works if I use pre-built AmazonLinux2 AMI (GPU and EKS). The AMI I built on Ubuntu does not work. So, there are mistakes with my Ubuntu AMI. I posted procedures of how I built the EKS, GPU AMI on Ubuntu. Any idea what the mistakes are?